# struts2 and Jquery

Tags: jquery, struts2

I'm adding rows in a table dynamically in a JSP Table using Jquery and want to send that table data in Struts2 action List ( for e.g. )

Below is Code for Adding Rows dynamically, like in below Link :

[*how-to-add-remove-table-rows-dynamically-using-jquery*](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-add-remove-table-rows-dynamically-using-jquery.php)

And i want to send this Table Data to Struts 2 Action in a List of Employee Object lets say :

```
public class MyAction extends BaseAction {

   private List<Emp> emplList ;

   // Getters + Setters of emplList
```

I tried to use `s:iterator` but its not working, `emplList.size` is 0 ( zero ) in `Action`

can someone please suggest me or give some sample Code

Answer (score 0):

Given that `Emp` has `name` and `mail` properties with setters and getters, there are probably 2 ways of doing this:

1. You modify your jQuery javascript so that the end result of added rows will become something like:

```html
<input type="text" name="emplList[0].name"   value="Name1"/>  
<input type="text" name="emplList[0].email"  value="email1"/>
<input type="text" name="emplList[1].name"   value="Name2"/>
<input type="text" name="emplList[1].email"  value="Email2"/>
```

and then, after submit is pressed your `List` of `Emp` in `Action` should be populated.

The downside of this solution is that you have to provide for **correct indexing** before sending the data to the server (could be tricky if you delete rows in process of building of data table)

2. To avoid indexing hassle, in your Action you could declare 2 Lists

   `private List<String> names;
    private List<String> emails;`

   in that case, end result of your javascript would be

```html
<input name="names" value="name1" />
<input name="emails" value="email1" />
<input name="names" value="name2" />
<input name="emails" value="email2" />
```

after the submit, two new lists (`names`, `emails`) on server side will be filled, from which you could created your desires `List` of `Emp` with something like

`emplList.add(new Emp(names.get(i),emails.get(i)));` for each `i`